# Игра угадай число и switch

Tags: c++, функции, switch, ввод

Всем здравствуйте! Есть вот такой кусок кода. В конце кода пользователю предлагаю сделать выбор: играть дальше или отказаться.
Не могу понять следующее:
Как через switch сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на 1 - игра начиналась заново, при нажатии на 2 - заканчивалась, а при любом другом числе не равно 1 и 2 выдавала ошибку и просила снова ввести 1 или 2, ну и соответственно при вводе 1 или 2 выполняла вышеописанные задачи.

Пробовал заворачивать все в функцию - работает криво.

Спасибо за уделённое время!:)

```
int main()
{

    srand(time(0));
    int random = 1 + rand() % 1001;
    int userNumber;
    int userChose;

    cout << "I randomed some number from 1 to 1000." << endl;
    cout << "Please, try to catch it!" << endl;
    cout << "Good luck!" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Please enter your number: ";
    cin >> userNumber;
    cout << endl;

    while (userNumber != random)
    {

        if (userNumber < random) {
            cout << "Your number less then i randomed;" << endl;
            cout << "Please, enter your number again: ";
            cin >> userNumber;
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (userNumber > random) {
            cout << "Your number is bigger then i randomed" << endl;
            cout << "Please, enter your number again: ";
            cin >> userNumber;
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (userNumber == random) {
            cout << "You got it!" << endl << endl;
            cout << "If you want to continue the game enter 1" << endl;
            cout << "If you want to exit the game enter 2" << endl;
            cout << "Your chose: ";
            cin >> userChose;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите игру в отдельную функцию, скажем, `game()`.

Тогда ваш код будет иметь примерно такой вид:

```
for(int code; cin >> code; cout << "1 - еще раз, 2 - выход")
{
    if (code == 1) game();
    else if (code == 2) break;
    cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите ";
}
```

Ну, или воспользуйтесь `switch-case`, только тогда простого `break` для выхода будет мало:

```
for(int code; cin >> code; cout << "1 - еще раз, 2 - выход")
{
    bool quit = false;
    switch(code)
    {
    case 1: game(); break;
    case 2: quit = true; break;
    default:
        cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите ";
    }
    if (quit) break;
}
```

Comment: Как раз тот случай, когда `goto Quit;` для выхода из цикла наиболее логичен

Comment: @avp "Нет! На это я пойтить не могу!" (с)